Sound getting Noisy
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, The output sound gets noisy sometimes. There is no stable pattern to it. But this happens regardless of what audio device is used. When I run
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio

The issue is solved temporarily, but every now and then I have to run this command. Is there a fix to this and why is this happening?

The issue occurs as pulse audio detects 2 sound cards and sends audio output to both the cards.
sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*

Gives:
                    USER          PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  gdm          1344 F.... pulseaudio
                     userName     1718 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  gdm          1344 F.... pulseaudio
                     userName     1718 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D3p:   userName     1718 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c:   userName     1718 F...m pulseaudio

Before restarting the audio and
                     USER         PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  gdm          1344 F.... pulseaudio
                     userName     9223 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  gdm          1344 F.... pulseaudio
                     userName     9223 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D3p:   userName     9223 F...m pulseaudio

Restarting pulseaudio would fix the issue.
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio

